# PHP Composer: Setting dynamic variable paths in the autoload function

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have recently started using composer to autoload my classes. But I find I have to upload each directory individually as I store an `src/` directory and a `tests/` directory foreach class. For example:

```
  "Core\\Router\\": "system/Core/Router/src/",
  "Core\\Router\\Tests\\": "system/Core/Router/tests/",
  "Core\\DatabaseManager\\": "system/Core/DatabaseManager/src/",
  "Core\\DatabaseManager\\Tests\\": "system/Core/DatabaseManager/tests/"
```

Is there a way to make it so that composer reads a variable path? e.g.

```
  "Core\\{VARIABLE_PATH}\\": "system/Core/{VARIABLE_PATH}/src/",
  "Core\\{VARIABLE_PATH}\\Tests\\": "system/Core/{VARIABLE_PATH}/tests/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "dynamic paths" are not supported.
A "component" folder layout, where "src" and "tests" are inside a subfolder is definitely nice, but at the moment there is no "automatical" autoloading support for this structure.

When you use one namespace "application\namespace" for your `system/core/` folder, all classes are scanned (including src and tests) and become part of the autoloading map. In other words autoloading will work, but when thinking of  production usage, then your map will be quite big, because it includes the test classes also. And that might result in a speed decrease. If you do not care about this, then everything is fine: autoloading will work fine, when using a single `App\Namespace\Core` mapped to the top folder `\system\Core`.

If you care, then you could try to divide `src` and `tests` manually by using `autoload` and `autoload-dev` sections and listing the individual component folders under the top namespace. That's tedious, but will result in a smaller classmap for production (no-dev).

You can define multiple dirs to search in, like so:

`composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Namespace\\": 
            [
                "ComponentOne/src", 
                "ComponentTwo/src"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Namespace\\Tests": 
            [
                "ComponentOne/tests", 
                "ComponentTwo/tests"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. Glad i could help a bit.